# VAT Issue on Orders

Tags: woocommerce

We have an issue on WooCommerce where we need it to include the VAT on Orders to customers in Belgium even if they add a valid VAT number.

This is due to our shipping warehouse being in Belgium and we need to charge VAT to all customers, by law.

Is there any way of customising WooCommerce?

Thanks

We Use 'EU VAT Assistant' to control VAT charge on our website.

Comment: In shipping zones add your zone and taxes.